# Listing all files in subdirectories but excluding specific filetypes

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have the following structure of files:

```
└── artifacts
    ├── IMAGES
    │       ├── Lab1.1
    │       │   ├── test1.tar.gz
    │       │   ├── .
    │       │   ├── .
    │       │   ├── .
    │       │   └── test2.txt
    │       └── Lab1.2
    │           ├── test1_1.tar.gz
    │           ├── .
    │           ├── .
    │           └── test2_1.txt
    ├── INSTANCE
    │   ├── CONFIGURATION
    │   │   ├── CUSTOM1.json
    │   │   ├── CUSTOM2.json
    │   │   └── CUSTOM3.json
```

The problem is when i do:

```
    def find_files_under_directory(self, directory_path):
        dir_path = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))
        int_path = os.path.join(dir_path, directory_path)
        data = pathlib.Path(int_path)
        data.rglob("*")
        return list(data.rglob("*")
```

It returns:

`..././artifacts/IMAGES/`

`..././artifacts/IMAGES/Lab1`

`..././artifacts/IMAGES/Lab1.1/test1.tar.gz`

`..././artifacts/IMAGES/Lab1.1/test2.txt`

`..././artifacts/INSTANCE`

Firstly i want to exclude in the returned list of dirs that don't have files such as:

`..././artifacts/IMAGES/`

`..././artifacts/INSTANCE etc`

Secondly I want to exclude some file types, but i don't want to mess up the order in the list that gathers them. e.g (exclude all txt):

`.../..../artifacts/IMAGES/Lab1.1/test1.tar.gz`

`.../../artifacts/IMAGES/Lab1.1/test2.tar.gz`

`..././CUSTOM1.json`

`..././CUSTOM2.json`

`..././CUSTOM3.json etc`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `os.walk` and filter out `.txt` files:

```py
import os
import fnmatch

def non_txt_files(directory):
    for path, dirs, files in os.walk(directory):
        for file in files:
            if fnmatch.fnmatch(file, '*.txt'):
                continue
            yield os.path.join(path, file)

for file in non_txt_files('artifacts'):
    print(file)
```

Output:

```
artifacts\IMAGES\Lab1.1\test1.tar.gz
artifacts\IMAGES\Lab1.2\test1_1.tar.gz
artifacts\INSTANCE\CONFIGURATION\CUSTOM1.json
artifacts\INSTANCE\CONFIGURATION\CUSTOM2.json
artifacts\INSTANCE\CONFIGURATION\CUSTOM3.json
```

Another option using `pathlib`, but more generic per comment:

```py
from pathlib import Path

# Note 1: avoid using mutable defaults.
# Note 2: * indicates start of args that require keywords.
def list_files(directory, *, include=None, exclude=None):
    if include is None:
        include = ['*']
    if exclude is None:
        exclude = []
    for p in Path(directory).rglob('*'):
        if (p.is_file()
            and any(p.match(pat) for pat in include)
            and not any(p.match(pat) for pat in exclude)
        ):
            yield p

for file in list_files('artifacts', exclude=('*.txt', '*.tar.gz')):
    print(file)
```

Output:

```
artifacts\INSTANCE\CONFIGURATION\CUSTOM1.json
artifacts\INSTANCE\CONFIGURATION\CUSTOM2.json
artifacts\INSTANCE\CONFIGURATION\CUSTOM3.json
```

Comment: And what if let's say that under dir \artifacts there are .tar.gz files and i want them to be excluded too.